# How to get an excel cell to show the time it was selected

Tags: excel, time, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to create a table that tracks downtime for a production machine. the operator will be using a table with the columns down time start and down time stop. each time something happens that they have to leave the station I want them just to have to click the empty cell under downtime stat title and the time will appear/ log itself in the cell then the same for downtime stop.

I under stand how `=now()` works but then it shows the time when the file is opened, i want it to display only when the cell is selected.

Any help is much appreciated! I have never had to do anything like this in  excel before.

Comment: or you could press   CTRL + SHIFT + : to add the current timestamp

Comment: i need for this to be as fool proof as possible so it only take half a second to perform. CTRL + SHIFT + : is too much to ask the operator to remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some VBA for this. In your VBE (alt+f11) go to your worksheet and use something like the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Check to see if the click/selected cell is in columns A or B
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then

        'Make sure just one cell is selected:
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

            'Update the value
            Target.Value = Now()
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Here we are using the `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event. This event will fire any time a selection change is detected on the worksheet in which this code is placed. When the change is detected it will test to see if the selection was in columns A or B. It will also test to insure that only one cell was clicked (otherwise highlighting those columns would cause every row in the column to update with the time, which would be bad). If that all passes, then it just sets the selected cell's (target) value to the current time.

Comment: thank you for the help, does it matter if it is in a worksheet with a bunch of other macros i guess you would call them from previous people adding to it?

Comment: It depends on what those other macros are. Are they also triggering off of sheet events? If so, then you might end up causing an infinite loop and eventually a... <puts on sunglasses> ...stack overflow. If that is the case then you'll want to take a look at `application.enableEvents` which you can set to `true/false` to keep your events from firing while vba is running.

Comment: the only thing that i see that might interfere is a line that says 'Makes the screen not freak out while the macro runs'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False.

Also, how do I make the macro only apply to a certain number of rows from those columns?

Comment: That just forces excel to not update the UI while the code is running. No worries there. I would pay more attention to the name of the subroutines. If you see any subs in the worksheet's code that start with `Worksheet_<some action>()` then you'll need to insure that stuff in that code doesn't touch the columns in this subroutine, or trigger off of them  where it uses them as a `target`. Likewise, if you have any code in any routine that `Select` or `Activate` on a cell in these columns or the columns themselves, then you'll need to wrap that code in `EnableEvents=False`...`EnableEvents=True`

Comment: At any rate, you'll know if it's bombs since Excel will lock up hard and you'll have to force quit. Just save a copy before dumping the code in the worksheet so you can restore.

Comment: I added the code to the top of the VBE and saved it, the columns that need to have the click time are G and H so i  replaced A:B with G:H and when i went back to the spread sheet and selected one of those cells nothing happened

Comment: Insure that you are placing the code in the Worksheet's code, not a seperate module or "ThisWorkbook" code. Also, sometimes it helps to close and reopen when copying and pasting event code around.

Comment: ok so i just saved all the old code in a word file in case i need it again and deleted everything out of the VBE. is there anything other than saving the VBE that i need to do to get it to work? i tried closing and reopening excel and clicking in columns G and H still doesnt do anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113959/discussion-between-samql-and-jnevill).